# Jenkins Flutter command not found

Tags: android, ios, flutter, jenkins, devops

I'm trying to use Jenkins with my Flutter project, however, when I build the project I get the following error
`flutter command not found`.

I have added the following code in the `.bash_profile`
`export PATH=$PATH/Users/andrey/Developer/flutter/bin`

I also have added the following in the **Global properties**:

```
Name:ANDROID_HOME
Value:/Users/andrey/Library/Android/sdk

Name:HOME
Value:/Users/andrey

Name:PATH
Value:/$PATH/Users/andrey/Developer/flutter/bin
```

I have the following shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
flutter build apk--debug
flutter test
```

Comment: Are you added path to Flutter to Jenkins machine Environment?

Comment: @fartem yes I've added it in the Name: Path from the Global Properties from above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it was failing is because the PATH variable was not exactly the same as when the `echo $PATH` was being inputed in the terminal.